# Make position:sticky follow an element outside of its parent container?

Tags: css

So what I've got is a landing page that should show a.) a header b.) a large picture that fills the screen on desktop and c.) a navbar. The navbar should scroll along the page once it's reached the top of the page.

Now, the only way I would know to ensure that all three of those elements fit perfectly into the viewport on desktop is with max-height: 100vh in a parent element. However, I'd like to make the navbar scroll along once it's at the top of the screen. This isn't possible when the navbar is in its own container, because it'll stop scrolling along once it's hit the bottom of its container.

Does anyone know of a fix? Below is a sample of the structure I'm trying to use right now:

```
<div class="container-top">
  <header>
    <!--- ...header content... -->
  </header>

  <div>
    <img src="1080p_image.png">
  </div>

  <nav class="sticky-top">
    <!-- ...navbar content... -->
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="other-content">
    <!-- ...other content... -->
</div>
```

```
.container-top{
  max-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img{
  width: 100vw;
}

header{
  background-color: darkgray;
  height: 5rem;

  z-index: 1;
}

nav{
  background-color: darkgray;
  height: 5rem;

  z-index: 1;
}

.sticky-top{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.other-content{
  height: 100rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your nav into its own div below div.container-top?

```
<div class="container-top">
  <header>
    <!-- ...header content -->
  </header>
  <div>
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <nav class="sticky-top">
    <!-- ..navbar content... -->
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="other-content">
    <!-- ...other content... -->
</div>
```

And if you want these elements to take up 100vh:

```
.container-top {
  max-height: 75vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  max-height: 25vh;
}
```

Lemme know how that works for ya.